# Creating/managing site programmatically

Tags: apex, managed-package, force.com-sites, postinstall

We are creating a managed package that contains a few Visualforce pages that should be public accessible. Everything works as expected, except for 1 thing:

*For each org we have to create a new site in order to make that VF page public.* That is not difficult, it doesn't take much time, but for a normal user it might become a real challenge.

So my question is:

**Is it possible(if so, how?) to create/manage existing site of an org in apex?**

Example 1:

- We install managed package on an org that has no site yet
- Postinstall script would run and then it should see that there are no active sites
- Then Postinstall script will create a site and edit *Public Access Setting* so that those VF pages can be public accessible

Example 2:

Same as Example 1, but that org already has an active site. In this case Postinstall script should only modify *Public Access Settings* of the existing site and add those VF pages to make them public.